# How to test long timeouts with Mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, oauth, mocha.js

I'm testing an extarnal server where I have no access to the code, I just know from the server its protocol [UMA](http://kantarainitiative.org/confluence/display/uma/Home), something related to the Ouath and the external endpoints.

I have been testing all the major capabilities of the system, however I need to test the timeout of the exchanged tokens between my server test and the external Test.
This timeout is set to one hour and I want to test some behaviour that happens after token expires.
The problem I don't have any clue of how to do it.... I mean I know the easy one make my test wait one hour, but I'm sure there is someway better of doing it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not get a token now, and that's the token you keep using from now on.  It shouldn't matter if the token has expired 5 minutes ago, or 5 months ago.

Comment: Could be an option.
However, I still have to wait one hour of doing test with the same token till it expires..

Comment: but you wait only the fist time, then you'd never need to wait again.

Comment: Yes of course, but I want (if it's possible) to do it all with just a call to my tests.
In one test I get the token and move it around the server and then i want to test wath happens when the token expires, without waiting...

Right now following what you said I have two different test one where I get the token and I do stuff. And another test with a expired token to test the expired token

Comment: I understand this is not ideal, but may be the best option short of running the server with a shorter token expiration.